Least Squares (LS) Estimatior LS vs. Linear Minimum Mean Squared Error (LMMSE) for Channel Estimation
I have performed the LS channel estimation based on the received pilot sequences yp  and pilot matrix P in MATLAB as following:
h_e_stack_LS = pinv(P)*(yp)/sqrt(N);

In the above code, N is the number of subcarriers used in the OFDM symbol.
When I estimated the channel using the LMMSE, I used the following method:
       SNR = 0:2:30; 
       SNRv=10.^(SNR./10);
       snr = 0 : length(SNR)

       up = P';
       down = P*P' + eye(size(P,1))/SNRv(snr);
       res = up/down/sqrt(N); %
       h_e_stack_LMMSE = res * (yp);

When plot the MSE performance of both estimators I get the graph as below:
My concern, I think that LMMSE should outperforms the LS estimator, why in my case it's difference.  I was wondering if the way I used for performing LMMSE estimator is correct or it needs to be corrected?

Do you compare the Least Mean Squared Error Filter to the Least Squared Filter?

I am comparing linear minimum mean square error (LMMSE) estimator vs least squares (LS) estimator. @Royi

Given the noise is Gaussian and the model is linear their performance should be the same.

I am using BEM channel model. In my code, why do I get different results ? is my code above correct or something is missing ?

I derived everything for you in the answer.

@Sajjad you are not simulating LS/LMMSE channel estimators but LS/LMMSE equalizers assuming perfect channel estimate AND, for the LMMSE, also perfect SNR estimate. Check the SNR perceived by the equalizer because your channel $h$ does not necessarily have unit power. For the simulation, because you are assuming perfect channel estimation, for each SNR, just generate ONE random channel and then simulate the equalization with say 10000 noise realization. The noise need to be generated according to the channel power and the desired SNR.

@AlexTP The code I provided above is indeed for LS/LMMSE channel estimators. The output of each step is the estimated channel. The figure is to calculate the MSE. The strange thing I see is that the MSE performance of LS is better than LMMSE. So I am wondering where is issue in that case.

@Sajjad ok I see, you did say $P$ was pilot, I saw it as the channel estimate, sorry for shooting from the hip. However everything else I said is true. The only random element here is the noise, and your channel power is probably not 1. Try the scalar channel first and check the simulation output.

@AlexTP It's the same issue. The LMMSE shows worse performance than LS estimator.

@Sajjad if you have the matlab lte toolbox, use this https://www.mathworks.com/help/lte/ref/lteequalizemmse.html: if you transmit only pilots no data, an equalizer is estimator. You can replace lteEqualizeMMSE by lteEqualizeZF to emulate the LS estimator. You also have access to the source code of these functions.

Your problem model is given by a simple linear operator, the convolution:
$$ \boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{h} \ast \boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{n} $$
Where:

$\boldsymbol{x}$ is the pilot sequence (Known).
$\boldsymbol{h}$ is the channel model (To be estimated).
$\boldsymbol{y}$ is the received signal (Known).
$\boldsymbol{n}$ is the noise samples (AWGN).

The problem can be written in a matrix form:
$$ \boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{h} + \boldsymbol{n} $$
The Least Squares solution of the linear system is the solution of the Least Squares problem:
$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{h}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{h} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$
The solution is given by $\hat{\boldsymbol{h}} = {\left( \boldsymbol{X}^{T} \boldsymbol{X} \right)}^{-1} \boldsymbol{X}^{T} \boldsymbol{y}$.
Though it should not be solved explicitly as above.
The LMMSE is a Bayesian Estimator which adds a probabilistic model both for the noise and the channel coefficients.
See:

Derive the Wiener Deconvolution Filter.
Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE), MMSE and LS - Are All of Them Regressor, Estimator and Predictor.
MMSE Estimation - Fusion of 2 Measurements.
Derivation of the LMMSE (Linear Minimum Mean Squared Error) Estimate and the MMSE Under Gaussian Prior.
Minimum Mean Square Estimator - Equivalent Expressions to Minimize.

In your case it ends up solving the following problem:
$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{h}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{h} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{h} \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$
Where $\lambda$ balances the inaccuracy in the model and the noise level. It is inversely proportional to the SNR.
The solution is given by $\hat{\boldsymbol{h}} = {\left( \boldsymbol{X}^{T} \boldsymbol{X} + \lambda \boldsymbol{I} \right)}^{-1} \boldsymbol{X}^{T} \boldsymbol{y}$.
It matches the LS for $\lambda = 0$ which matches infinite SNR.
Now the question is, why the LMMSE is much worse in your code?
The answer is the model you generated the data with does not match the model of the LMMSE.
The LMMSE assumes the channel coefficients are also stochastic. Hence when you generate the received data, $\boldsymbol{y}$ you should add small noise to channel. So the model is something like:
$$ \boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{X} \left( \boldsymbol{h} + \boldsymbol{w} \right) + \boldsymbol{n} $$
Where $\boldsymbol{w}$ is the noise which models the uncertainty in the channel model.

The code I provided above for LMMSE is similar to your derivation, but I get the MSE in case of LMMSE is worse than LS, is that logic?

@Sajjad, I added an answer why it seems the LMMSE is worse. The answer is the data in your code does not match the model of the MMSE estimator.

I added the way I generate the channel and do the convolution with the signal, how can I add the w in that case ?
